# excel interop string array to range, not showing as formulas

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am using excel interop,
I have a function where I set a 2d string array to range, the range is set of formulas such as

```
{"=COUNT(A12:A300)","=COUNT(B12:B300)","=COUNT(C12:C300)"}
```

and I have a simple function that writes the array to the range

```
    private void WriteStringRangeToExcel(string[,] s, int rowNumber, int cellStart)
    {
        Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)ws.Cells[rowNumber, cellStart];
        Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)ws.Cells[rowNumber + s.GetLength(0) - 1, s.GetLength(1)];
        Excel.Range range = ws.get_Range(c1, c2);
        range.Formula = s;            
    }
```

the weird thing is, when I open the excel it won't show them as formulas but as strings (I mean there is no calculation in the sheet but just the strings as saved in the array)
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't set the formula to the string property, you set the *array*. You don't use the 2D array anywhere else. Why did you use an array in the first place? Just set `Formula` to the string you want

Answer (score 0):

Needed to insert the data into value, and then set the value as a formula

```
    private void WriteStringRangeToExcel(string[,] s, int rowNumber, int cellStart)
    {
        Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)ws.Cells[rowNumber, cellStart];
        Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)ws.Cells[rowNumber + s.GetLength(0) - 1, s.GetLength(1)];
        Excel.Range range = ws.get_Range(c1, c2);
        range.Value = s;
        range.Value = range.Formula;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let's try:

```
 range.Formula = "=COUNT(A12:A300)"; //The formula will automatically transform accordingly
```

or i think you need convert `{"=COUNT(A12:A300)","=COUNT(B12:B300)","=COUNT(C12:C300)"}` to 2d array then using

```
range.value= s; //but this may take few seconds to show results
```

Comment: It will take a long time to execute this.